# Custom scaffolding xproj project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, scaffolding, sidewaffle

I'm trying to write a custom scaffolding for my asp.core project in visual studio.
I created new extensibility project that use SideWaffle templates to generate files and necessary staff.
I have problem with one line. My CodeGenerator context can't get valid codeLanguage from xproj project. 
Csproj project work fine.
Maybe someone have similar problem and can help me ?

```
var codeLanuguage = Context.ActiveProject.GetCodeLanguage();
```

Comment: My personal view is that .NET Core in VS2015 won't have a future (like WPF in VS2005). You will have to use VS2017, which is already in RC.